# Unity build issue - GooglePlayGamesManifest and GameServicesManifest

Tags: unity, google-play-services

I have added leaderboard to my unity game for which I have used the google play services plugin. But when I try to build, this is the error I get:

```
 Execution failed for task 'processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID@value value= 
(\728999946156) from [:unityLibrary:GameServicesManifest.plugin] AndroidManifest.xml:10:13-42 
is also present at [:unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin] AndroidManifest.xml:20:13-46 value= 
(\u003728999946156).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:9- 
10:45 to override.
```

Here's what's in the first manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file was automatically generated by the Google Play Games plugin for Unity
 Do not edit. -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.example.games.mainlibproj"    
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
<application>
    <!-- The space in these forces it to be interpreted as a string vs. int -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="\u003728999946156" />        
    <!-- Keep track of which plugin is being used -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.unityVersion"
        android:value="\u0020.20.20" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
</application>
```

and the second file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.example.games.mainlibproj">
<application>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value = "\728999946156" />
<activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity" android:theme = 
"@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Presumably you tried following the suggestion in the error message: `Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:9- 
10:45 to override.` - what happened when you tried that?

Comment: @DMGregory , yes, I have done that now and this is the error that's showing up: D8: Program type already present: com.google.example.games.mainlibproj.BuildConfig

Comment: Looks like that should be in your question then.

Comment: @DMGregory , I just restarted unity now and the problem is not there anymore. Not sure why that happened. Thanks for your help.....

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my unity project and the problem no longer exists. I'm not sure how it got resolved....