# Unity Build is showing GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib' is Missing.?

Tags: unity, c#

I was trying to build my unity project but it is showing this[image: ScreenShot of error] GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib' is missing AndroidManifest.xml file. UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)

some more information  i used cloudOnce but deleted that from my project

Comment: [Sounds similar to this prior Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/186448/39518)

Comment: Yes, i also saw that but did not get any clue there it was mentioned that I restarted the unity and got resolved and mine is not solved by that

Answer (score 1):

your problems sounds [like this one](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1674392/android-manifest-xml-missing-build-failed-need-hel.html) where the problem was the folder name.

All you have to do is change the name of `GoogleMobileAdsPlugin`
folder in `Plugins/Android` into `GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib` and the problem should be solved